# How to combine "lsof -i :port" and "kill pid" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command

How do i combine these two commands in the bash:

```
lsof -i :port
kill pid
```

The first one returns the PID i want to kill to release the port. The second one kills the returned PID.

I am doing this because I don´t know of any way to kill a jetty webserver within the Netbeans IDE on OSX. Is there a way?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use $():

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:port)
```

Comment: How can I make this into an alias command? Like `alias k4="kill $(lsof -t -i:port)"`?

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
kill -9 `lsof -t -i:port`
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made